# nginx rewrite URLs Vanillaforums

Tags: nginx

I've been playing with the Nginx configuration trying to get SEO-friendly URLs for my Vanillaforums installation on Nginx, however, I'm pretty stumped.

Based on this URL https://serverfault.com/questions/556207/nginx-try-files-to-rewrite-html-into-clean-url I came up with this current configuration

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ $uri @rwtest;
    }

    location @rwtest {
        add_header X-Debug-Msg "uw0tm8";
        rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I can go to the page directly (non-SEO friendly URL) and it works, but when I try to use the "clean" URL, I just get a 404 error. I also do not get the message "uw0tm8" in the header, which leads me to believe that rwtest is not getting run for whatever reason

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'd try replacing your location / block with

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

and getting rid of the @rwtest block.

A great resource is http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls under "Front Controller Pattern based packages"

Comment: This solution doesn’t work anymore with Vanilla forum 2.3. If someone know how to make it work with nginx…

Comment: Having same problem with Vanilla 2.3.  @SamuelDeBacker, did you ever get yours working?

Comment: @AndrewAngell No, I use the forum without clean URLs.

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to add below option in `/conf/config.php`

```
$Configuration['Garden']['RewriteUrls'] = true;
```

2) Just change the the `@vanilla` block in nginx configuration file

```
location @vanilla {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?p=$uri&$args last;
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm for me - thanks, the only thing that may help others is that this is in addition to all the configuration changes to nginx conf recommended by vanilla at https://docs.vanillaforums.com/developer/backend/server-nginx/ and replacing the @vanilla definition

Comment: @skv great .. :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was

```
index index.php;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?p=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;

  # Your PHP Setup
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I then added `$Configuration['Garden']['RewriteUrls'] = true;` to my config.php as per AShish Tiwari's answer.